# Resize functionality does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I need to hide my main navigation menu if the browser is less than 768px. 
Function triggers on resize. But the navigation menu hides at 784px instead. 
    Here's the code:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    var windowSize = jQuery( window ).width();
    if(jQuery("#main-navigation").css('display') == 'none' && windowSize > 768) {
        jQuery("nav#main-navigation").css("display", "block");
    }
    if(windowSize < 768) {
        jQuery("nav#main-navigation").css("display", "none");
    }

});
```

Comment: Why not using medeia query instead of js code? Something like that: '@media (max-width: 767px) { #main-navigation { display: none;}}'

Comment: Nope. Due to another functionality of the site, this onresize displaying none is required ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have scrollbar. `$(window).widht()` returns you widht without scrollbar. If you want to have width with scroll width, you can use `window.innerWidth`

Comment: Awesome .. Its working, But for my knowledge I want to know why even google not even jquery api not showing widht(). innerWidth is showing ...

Comment: https://github.com/eddiemachado-zz/bones/issues/468#issuecomment-23626238